# Multiply a 2D matrix using scalar multiplication

Tags: java, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have to write a program that prompts the user to input dimensions for a 2D matrix as well as values for the matrix.

After that, I have to multiply the matrix by 2 and print the result.

I have the program almost completed, but I can't figure out how to multiply the matrix and store those values into a new matrix. Here's my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class MatrixMultiplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 

    System.out.println("Please enter the number of rows: ");
       int row = sc.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please enter the number of columns: ");
       int col = sc.nextInt();

    int[][] matrix = new int[row][col];

    System.out.println("Enter " + matrix.length + " rows and " + matrix[0].length + " columns: ");
    for (row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
        for (col = 0; col < matrix[row].length; col++) {
            matrix[row][col] = sc.nextInt(); 
        }
    }
    System.out.println();

    for (row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
        for (col = 0; col < matrix[row].length; col++) {
            System.out.print(matrix[row][col] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println(); 
    } 
}
}
```

I've looked everywhere for help and tried several different statements, but none of them seem to be quite right.

I know I have to use `for` loops, but like I said I'm not entirely sure how many to use, how to store the new values in a matrix and display it, etc, etc.

Any direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should define a Matrix class and store your data there. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_object_classes.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the first `double-for-loop` you need to declare the `second matrix` which will the element of the first but `*2`, so :

```
int[][] matrixDouble = new int[row][col];
for (row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
    for (col = 0; col < matrix[row].length; col++) {
        matrixDouble[row][col] = matrix[row][col]*2; //element -> *2 -> store in new matrix
        System.out.print(matrixDouble[row][col] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println(); 
}
```

In each box of the new `matrix`, it will store the number at the same position in the first matrix but a `2` factor

You can print it at same time

---

Depending on how you need to solve it, but you can move the operation in the first `for-loop` :

```
for (row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
    for (col = 0; col < matrix[row].length; col++) {
        matrix[row][col] = sc.nextInt(); 
        matrixDouble[row][col] = matrix[row][col]*2;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm kind of kicking myself right now, because I got so frustrated over this earlier. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to try solve the problem yourself, after thinking for more than `3` hours you can search the internet for solution

you need to change the last loop in this way :

```
for (row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
        for (col = 0; col < matrix[row].length; col++) {
            System.out.print(matrix[row][col]*2 + " ");
        }
        System.out.println(); 
}
```

i have multiplied it by two inside the loop in this line :

`System.out.print(matrix[row][col]*2 + " ");`

Comment: `3 hours`... just curious where that comes from?

Comment: @tima when i was starting to solve such problems, i've tried to write a program which show a number is prime or not, i've tried to write it myself without searching the internet, i took `3` hours :D

Comment: @tima in that case i learned how to use a `flag`, how does `break` works, and what does `return` really means in methods

Comment: I did stare at my screen for a while trying to figure this out, haha. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Why not define a Matrix class and use that?

Here is a Matrix.java:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Matrix {
        private double[][] matrix;
        private int rows;
        private int cols;

        public Matrix ( double [][] m ) {
                rows   = m.length;
                cols   = m[0].length;
                matrix = m;
        }

        public Matrix ( Matrix m  ) {
                rows   = m.rows;
                cols   = m.cols;
                matrix = new double[rows][cols];
                for ( int i=0; i<rows; i++ ) {
                        for ( int j=0; j<cols; j++ ) {
                                matrix[i][j] = m.matrix[i][j];
                        }
                }    
        }

        public void scale( double M ) {
                for ( int i=0; i<rows; i++ ) {
                        for ( int j=0; j<cols; j++ ) {
                                matrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j] * M;
                        }
                }
        }

        public double[][] getMatrix() {
                return matrix;
        }

        public void print () {
                for ( int i=0; i<rows; i++ ) {
                        for ( int j=0; j<cols; j++ ) {
                                System.out.print( matrix[i][j] + ", " );
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                }
        }
}
```

Here is a test program that demos Matrix:

```
import java.io.*;
public class RunMatrix {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
                System.out.println( "Starting RunMatrix." );
                double [][] a = new double[][]{
                        { 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 },
                        { 2.1, 2.2, 2.3 },
                        { 3.1, 3.2, 3.3 },
                };
                Matrix m = new Matrix(a);
                m.print();

                System.out.println( "Scale by 2." );
                m.scale(2.0);
                m.print();

                Matrix n = new Matrix(m);
                System.out.println( "here is n." );
                n.print();

                System.out.println( "Scale n by 2." );
                n.scale(2.0);
                n.print();

                System.out.println( "m is still." );
                m.print();
        }
}
```

Here is output of the above:

```
Starting RunMatrix.
1.1, 1.2, 1.3,
2.1, 2.2, 2.3,
3.1, 3.2, 3.3,
Scale by 2.
2.2, 2.4, 2.6,
4.2, 4.4, 4.6,
6.2, 6.4, 6.6,
here is n.
2.2, 2.4, 2.6,
4.2, 4.4, 4.6,
6.2, 6.4, 6.6,
Scale n by 2.
4.4, 4.8, 5.2,
8.4, 8.8, 9.2,
12.4, 12.8, 13.2,
m is still.
2.2, 2.4, 2.6,
4.2, 4.4, 4.6,
6.2, 6.4, 6.6,
```